# Similar entries 7.x-2.0 known error

Tags: 7

When I try the view for out-of-the-box use that comes with Similar entries 7.x-2.0 i get this error:

Strict warning: Declaration of similar_handler_argument_nid::query() should be compatible with that of views_handler_argument_numeric::query() in require_once() (line 11 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\similar\views\similar_handler_argument_nid.inc).

I searched drupal.org and found someone with the same problem: http://drupal.org/node/1270404
with no answer since September so I decided to try here.

I have tried the beta1 and dev version, run cron, tried to find some tutorial on how to use the module, read the readme for the module and had no luck. Am I missing something obvious?

I also get the error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'score' in 'order clause'

Answer (score 1):

This is not you, it is a bug in the module. I'm sorry to say that the fact that the bug goes back to September does not bode well for a fix.  Neither does the fact that there is only one active maintainer who has not made any changes since the releases in August.  If you are a coder, you might try fixing the code.  If not, you may want to look for other options.

Comment: OK, thanks. BTW I created something with views that can be used as similar content so no need for code fixing